# LIEF: how to catch exceptions

Tags: python-3.x, exception

Good morning folks,

I'm in front of a problem.

I am using the package lief (python3 package) to parse some ELF binaries.
It happens that some exceptions are raised.
I would like to catch them to apply some modifications depending on the exception raised.
Unfortunately, I cannot manage to catch them properly.

Here's what I tried:

```
 try :
     binary = lief.ELF.parse(sys.argv[-1])
 except lief.exception:
     print("lief exception")
 except:
     print("all exceptions")
```

It always shows "all exceptions"..
Here's the link of the API: [API LINK](https://lief.quarkslab.com/doc/api/python/index.html#exceptions)

Thank you for your help !

Comment: Have you tried catching other exceptions like `lief.bad_file`? Or maybe `lief.parser_error`

Comment: Yes I tried, actually I wrote some code wrongly before the try/except, and I saw that it's not seen as an exception (the except: print("all exceptions") doesn't work at all)
So I guess there is a print somewhere in the package